# WinHttpException: A connection with the server could not be established

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

I have asp.net core application with identity server... when i try to run getting below error message.

WinHttpException: A connection with the server could not be established

System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.

System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
IOException: IDX10804: Unable to retrieve document from: 'http://localhost:5000/.well-known/openid-configuration'.

Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever+d__8.MoveNext()
InvalidOperationException: IDX10803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'http://localhost:5000/.well-known/openid-configuration'.

Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager+d__24.MoveNext()

Answer (score 1):

I have to run the Identity server application along with web application to connect with Identity server project.

As I'm not running IDP i got connection establish error :

"A connection with the server could not be established"